# Definitions of Catalan surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

I have began reading about ruled surfaces, and I would like to ask a question about the definition of a Catalan's surface.

The definition says that Catalan surfaces are ruled surfaces whose rulings are parallel to a fixed plane(Directrix plane). In the book "Encycopedia of analytical surfaces" by Krivoshapko/Ivanov, though, it says that a Catalan surface is a ruled surface, with vector equation of the form:
$$ \overline{x}=\overline{x}(u,v)=\overline{r}(u)+v\overline{e}(u), $$ 
where
$$\overline{e}''(u)\neq \overline{0}$$
and
$$ (\overline{e}(u),\overline{e}'(u),\overline{e}''(u))=0.$$
Why are these two definitions equivalent? I just can't see this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These are most definitely *not* equivalent. A cylinder (where the rulings are parallel, i.e., $\vec e(u)$ is constant) meets the first definition but most definitely not the second, as it stands.

The natural equivalence is with the second condition alone. It says that the vectors $\vec e,\vec e{}',\vec e{}''$ are everywhere linearly dependent. This means that the plane spanned by $\vec e$ and $\vec e{}'$ is constant (and conversely). This will be the plane to which $\vec e(u)$ is always parallel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What I don't seem to get from what you wrote though, is the reason why we have a constant plane spanned. I mean why don't we have different planes for different values of u? Shouldn't we find a constant vector $\overline{n}$ which is perpendicular to $\overline{e}(u)$(i.e $  \overline{e}\cdot\overline{n}=0$??

Comment: Yes, the direction of $\vec e\times\vec e{}'$ does not change, as $(\vec e\times\vec e{}')' = \vec e\times \vec e{}''$. Since $\vec e{}'' = \lambda\vec e + \mu\vec e{}'$ for some functions $\lambda,\mu$, $(\vec e\times\vec e{}')' = \mu\vec e\times\vec e{}'$; this tells us that the vector $\vec e\times\vec e{}'$ does not change direction as $u$ varies.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you very much for your time. Have a a wonderful day.

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept the answer once you're satisfied, so that the question does not remain unanswered. You might also want to check out my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: Looks really well made. I will definately check it out in detail. Thank you very much for pointing it out.